# Preservation of the Markov property under the weak convergence of the joint distributions

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, markov-chains, weak-convergence

Assume that a sequence of joint probability distributions $\{F_n(x,y,z)\}_{n}$ converges weakly to a joint probability distribution $F^*(x,y,z)$.

If under $F_n(x,y,z)\ \forall n$, we have $X-Y-Z$ (i.e., $X$ and $Z$ are conditionally independent given $Y$), can we say that this is also the case under $F^*(x,y,z)$? In other words, does weak convergence preserve this Markov chain?

Assume the support set of $Y$ is finite, e.g. Y has a probability mass function on $\{1,2,3\}$.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

No. Let $Y_n$ be a normal distribution with mean zero and variance $1/n$, and let $X_n=Z_n$ be the signum of $Y_n$, the function with value $1$ if $Y_n$ is nonnegative and value $-1$ if $Y_n$ is negative. Then $X_n$ and $Z_n$ are independent conditionally on $Y_n$. Then $X_n$ and $Z_n$ are perfectly correlated with the same distribution and this is preserved in the limit. But the limit of the distributions of $Y_n$ is a point-measure concentrated on $0$. So conditional independence is not preserved under weak convergence.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Can we say anything when the alphabet size of $Y$ is finite? Assume that the support set of Y is the set $\{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: In that case, conditional independence is preserved.

Comment: Thanks. And is there any way to prove it? or any references? If it can be shown that the conditional mutual information $I(X:Z|Y)$ is lower semi-continuous in $F(x,y,z)$ for finite $Y$, then this preservation could be proved. However, I couldn't show that...

Comment: There are references, but they are probably not very convenient. Implicitly, there is a proof in "[Distributional Strategies for Games with Incomplete Information](http://web.stanford.edu/~milgrom/publishedarticles/DistributionalStrategies.pdf)" by Milgrom and Weber (1985). A fairly comprehensive discussion of weak convergence and conditional independence can be found in "The topology of information on the space of probability measures over Polish spaces" by Barbie and Gupta (2014), preprint [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6364).

Comment: Thanks a lot. In the last paper you mentioned, a sufficient condition for preserving this conditional independence is the convergence in the topology of information. Then later, in section 6, they also provide a sufficient condition that weak* convergence becomes equivalent to convergence in the topology of information.

Comment: However, it seems that just from the fact that $Y$ has a finite support set, we cannot conclude that weak* convergence leads to convergence in the topology of information. Although it has a continuous density with respect to counting measure, we know nothing whether $X$ and $Z$ also have a continuous density with respect to any measure...So, are you sure that just by knowing that $Y$ has a probability mass function on say $\{1,2,3\}$, one can conclude the preservation of conditional independence? Thanks

Comment: @Peter You can do things "by hand" in your case.  The point is that conditional independence is not preserved by weak convergence, but independence is.  If $X^*$ and $Z^*$ are the codomains of $X$ and $Z$, respectively, you are looking at independent measures on the three spaces $X^*\times\{1\}\times Z^*$, $X^*\times\{2\}\times Z^*$, $X^*\times\{3\}\times Z^*$ if you have conditional independence given $Y$. On each of these spaces, independence is preserved and, since these three sets are "continuity sets", qua having an empty boundary, the total measure of each of these three sets converges.

Comment: I see. Yes, that's true. Cheers